# "npm start" giving error when starting it

Tags: node.js, fiware-cosmos

When i start "npm start" it throws me error :

[cosmos-auth@cosmos-instance cosmos-auth]$ npm start

> cosmos-auth@1.0.0-next start /home/cosmos-auth/fiware-cosmos/cosmos-auth

node ./src/cosmos_auth.js

fs.js:642
 
 return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ''
  
  at Error (native)
  
  at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:642:18)
  
  at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:510:33)
   
 at Object. (/home/cosmos-auth/fiware-cosmos/cosmos-
auth/src/cosmos_auth.js:44:17)
    
at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    
at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    
at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! cosmos-auth@1.0.0-next start: `node ./src/cosmos_auth.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the cosmos-auth@1.0.0-next start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/cosmos-auth/.npm/_logs/2019-02-12T06_40_39_349Z-debug.log

Pls help?

Version of npm: 6.7.0

 nodejs: v6.16.0

 centos 7

Comment: Did you `npm install` beforehand?

Comment: yes i did npm install and it shows me only warning : npm WARN cosmos-gui@1.0.0-next No license field.

audited 277 packages in 2.026s
found 2 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Comment: Can you reveal the code in /home/cosmos-auth/fiware-cosmos/cosmos-
auth/src/cosmos_auth.js  or at least around line 44 of the file?

Comment: "key: fs.readFileSync(config.private_key_file),"